# Creating a print css style sheet

Tags: css, printing, css-selectors

I am looking to create a Print style sheet for a page where the data within a table is to be printed off. I've tried to use the :not selector to get all other elements on the page and remove them leaving the table. I thought the code below would work but it doesn't. Am I doing it wrong or does it just not work

```
not:(table){display: none;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is wrong, it's `:not(table) { display: none; }`

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)